# Error while evaluating eval command

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to run the following code. When I comment input1 command it works fine. I want to print both input1 and input using eval command. Can someone please guide me where I am wrong?

```
 `input = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,4,4,1]))
input1=input.eval()
sess= tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print(input.eval())
print(input1.eval())`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of issues with this code:

1. Do not name a variable `input`. It is a bad practice because `input` is the name of a built-in Python function to receive information from the shell.
2. You cannot call the method `.eval()` on a variable that is not yet initialized within a `Session` object.
3. The method `tf.initialize_all_variables()` is deprecated, use `tf.global_variables_initializer()` instead.
4. After running an `InteractiveSession`, it is good practice to close it by running `sess.close()`.

By applying the necessary updates, the code block below is what you want to run:

```
input_var = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,4,4,1]))

sess= tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(input_var.eval())
sess.close()

'Output':
[[[[-0.27064177]
   [-0.05596501]
   [-0.5900124 ]
   [ 0.35008416]]

  [[ 2.5793896 ]
   [-0.9429237 ]
   [-1.8345704 ]
   [-0.45560673]]

  [[ 0.26966783]
   [-0.6355145 ]
   [ 0.13357505]
   [ 0.07976766]]

  [[ 1.0399019 ]
   [-0.8509619 ]
   [ 0.8938987 ]
   [ 0.279952  ]]]]
```

Comment: Input is in no way reserved

Comment: True, I'll update that. However, using it is bad practice as it is an inbuilt Python function. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Built-in. But yes, much better now.